# Помогите разобраться с функцией

Tags: javascript

Задача заключается в том, чтобы создать функцию, которая возвращает сумму последовательности целых чисел. Последовательность определяется 3 значениями: начало, конец, шаг.
Например:

```
sequenceSum (2,6,2) === 12 // 2 + 4 + 6
sequenceSum (1,5,1) === 15 // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
sequenceSum (1,5,3) === 5 // 1 + 4
```

Я делаю так:

```
  function sequenceSum (a, b, c) {
    let arr = [];
    let sum = 0;
    while (sum < b) {
      arr.push(sum += c)
    }
    console.log(arr.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current));
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что если число "а" отличается от "c", то результат будет ошибочный.

Comment: У вас замудренное решение.  Достаточно двух переменных: `x += c` (в начале `x=a`) и `sum += x`: `function sequenceSum (a, b, c) {
    let x = a;
    let sum = 0;
    while (x <= b) { /* включительно */
      sum += x;
      x += c;
    }
    console.log(sum);
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Могу предложить более быстрое решение. Оригинальная формула суммы последовательности от 1 до N - это N*(N+1)/2. Нам лишь нужно учесть пару моментов:

```js
function sum(a, b, i) {
  let min = Math.min(a, b) - i
  let r = Math.abs(a - b)
  let N = Math.trunc(r / i) + 1
  return N * min + i*(N*(N+1)/2)
}

console.log(sum(1, 3, 1)) // 6
console.log(sum(3, 5, 1)) // 12
console.log(sum(2, 6, 2)) // 12
console.log(sum(3, 7, 2)) // 15
console.log(sum(1, 5, 2)) // 9

console.log(sum(1, 4, 3)) // 5
console.log(sum(1, 5, 3)) // 5
console.log(sum(1, 6, 3)) // 5
console.log(sum(1, 7, 3)) // 12
```

Как видите, можно обойтись без циклов и массивов. И по времени быстрее и по памяти менее напряжно.